# Problemas con Apache 2.4 - Error 403 Prohibido

Tags: django, apache, virtualbox, windows-server

Estoy tratando de desplegar una aplicacion hecha con Django en Apache 2.4
Todo bien, me corre perfecto pero el problema esta cuando intento acceder desde otra parte fuera de mi Host. Que por cierto, estoy usando Windows Server 2009 en VirtualBox. Ya toque la parte del Firewall para permitir acceso a puertos externos y aun sigo encontrandome con ese error.

Esta es la configuracion del WSGI:

```
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/proyecto/app/todoapp">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "C:/Apache24/htdocs/proyecto/app/static/"
<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/proyecto/app/static/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```